# How to access url parameters in qt webview in android

Tags: android, qt, webview, qml

I want to get parameters which i am passing with url in webview.

Basically i am trying to hit some one dummy url with some parameters, based on these parameters i want to switch the view(webview to native) to play asset.

So i am capturing onUrlChanged change signal but i didnt see any arguments with url, **its coming upto ?**

Code:

Sample.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://10.1.100.42/Sau/dummy.tar.gz?AssetType=VIDEOS&AssetName=VIDEOS&AssetID=4000-4001&AssetURL=http://stream.hub.com/10846.m3u8">
    <input type="submit" value="Play Video" />
</form>
<form action="http://10.1.100.42/Sau/dummy.tar.gz?AssetType=AUDIOS&AssetName=VIDEOS&AssetID=4000-4001&AssetURL=http://stream.hub.com/10846.m3u8">
    <input type="submit" value="Play audio" />
</form>
<form action="http://10.1.100.42/Sau/dummy.tar.gz?AssetType=IMAGES&AssetName=VIDEOS&AssetID=4000-4001&AssetURL=http://stream.hub.com/10846.jpg">
    <input type="submit" value="Display image" />
</form>
<form action="http://10.1.100.42/Sau/dummy.tar.gz?AssetType=DOCUMENTS&AssetName=VIDEOS&AssetID=4000-4001&AssetURL=http://stream.hub.com/10846.pdf">
    <input type="submit" value="Display pdf" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtWebView 1.0
Rectangle{
    WebView {
        id: webview
        url: "Sample.html"
        anchors.fill: parent
        onUrlChanged:{
            console.log("url is "+url)
       }
  }
}
```

actual output on click on button:

```
url is http://10.1.100.42/Sau/dummy.tar.gz?
```

expected output on click on button:

```
url is http://10.1.100.42/Sau/dummy.tar.gz?AssetType=VIDEOS&AssetName=VIDEOS&AssetID=4000-4001&AssetURL=http://stream.hub.com/10846.m3u8
```

Comment: Did you try with `onLoadFinished` instead of `onUrlChanged`?

Comment: @Tarod onLoadFinished is not present in qt android

Comment: Try with the signal `loadingChanged` and get the url when `loadRequest` is `WebView.LoadSucceededStatus`